# How to pass data from app.component to child or other components in ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, events, ionic-framework, ionic3

I used the [events from ionic native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/). I have a login function that will emit an event that if a user has successfully logged in it will fire or publish an event that will pass all the data to the app component which is the root component of the entire application. The data that will be passed in base on the event that is the user details of the one who logged in. Yes I can do this using the [HTML 5 Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) but I instead use the [Ionic Event](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/). I only use the html5 localStorage for storing the Bearer Token which I got from the backend response when successfully logged in.

Here is the code in my **login.ts**

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
          Authorization: `Bearer ${result.data.data.token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });

        console.log(`Header response after authentication: ${headers}`)

        this.profileApi.loadDataAfterLogin(headers)
        .then(response => {
          console.log('Response after successful login', response)
          this.events.publish('user:success-login', response.data, Date.now());
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        });
```

And in my **app.component.ts**

I declare a property of a bunch of data.

```
username: string = null;
  email: string = null;
  firstName: string = null;
  lastName: string = null;
```

And now I have an event that will be fired when a successful login right? So the app component will subscribe to that event, which will set all my properties base on the data that is passed after successful authentication.

```
events.subscribe('user:success-login', (user, time) => {
      // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
      console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
      this.username = user.username;
      this.email = user.email;
      this.firstName = user.name.firstName;
      this.lastName = user.name.lastName;
    });
```

Now I want to pass all the data that I get from the event in the login passed to the app.component to all other components or child components.

For example I have a **messenger page** and I want to pass all the data from the **app component** that I created to that **messenger page component** or to other page or component? I also want this to pass to all other components because I will use this data.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to create a “global” service and use that as data layer. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: Oh thank you for that. I tried it and it is working. But can I ask you some question? Is it okay to store user details in web storage? I have read many articles and blogs or even some debate that mostly they said it is not a good practice.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by user details. Storing login/password is a bad idea, but other things like user settings or access token is perfectly ok

Comment: But using a global service and keep the data base from the event is much secured right?